# What is the exact location refered by "root" in Android Auto Backup rule?

Tags: android

Currently, I have the following backup rule for Android Auto Backup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <!-- /data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/databases -->
    <include domain="database" path="." />

    <!-- /data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/shared_prefs -->
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="com.xxx.yyy_preferences.xml" />
    
    <!-- /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files -->
    <include domain="external" path="." />
</full-backup-content>
```

Based on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

```
root : The directory on the filesystem where all private files belonging to this app are stored.
```

I was still wondering whether I should apply

```
<include domain="root" path="." />
```

May I know, which folder location, the root is actually referring to?

Thanks.